# Dell inspiron 15 - Hardware key being a pain

Tags: internet-connection, intel-wireless, inspiron

I enjoy the fact that instead of a switch on the side, Dell put a key down, but one problem... It stopped working.

I don't think this was caused by an update or anything; I accidentally pressed the wireless key, and now it's just refusing to turn back on.

Since I'm basically the guy who's meant to troubleshoot my grandmothers' computer, like a sort of unpaid I.T. guy.

If I can't get this Wireless back working, there'll be some major problems I don't want to deal with. I'm going to try to re-install the drivers, but that's all I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the problem is hardware or software. If software then just check the hardware ports which to see if wireless port is mentioned in the list or not... If not then just install it once again.